# DB2 Import with codepage modifier

Tags: import, db2, codepages

```
db2 => IMPORT FROM "/home/user/beetri/catalogue_data.csv" of del
       MODIFIED BY CODEPAGE=930 
INSERT INTO TEMP_UPLOAD_PRODUCT_ATTRIBUTES (PRODUCTGUID, GENERIC_NAME,
CATEGORY_GUID, LOCALEGUID, REALMGUID, CATEGORY_NAME, INGREDIENTS,
QUANTITY, NUTIRITION_FACTS, DOSE, CATCHING_PHRASE, PRODUCT_DESCRIPTION,
RECOMMENDED_FOR, PROMOTION_MSG, MESSAGE)
```

gives error/message as:

```
SQL3015N  An SQL error "-2754" occurred during processing.

SQL2754N  Codepage "930" cannot be converted to codepage "819".
```

Please advise.

Answer (score 2):

The database basically gives you your answer, and it's confirmed by [the Information Center topic on that SQLSTATE](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v9r7/topic/com.ibm.db2.luw.messages.sql.doc/doc/msql02754n.html):

> ***SQL2754N***
>
> Codepage *source-cp* cannot be converted to codepage *target-cp*.
>
> **Explanation**
>
> The database does not support codepage conversion between those two codepages.
>
> **User response**
>
> Please ensure your data is in a convertible codepage.

Comment: yes changing the codepage to 932 worked good. thanks for your help. Got anaother related issue I m facing. I m very new to DB2 and internationlization implementation. The issue now I m facing is:

Comment: IMPORT FROM "/home/user/beetri/cat.csv" of del MODIFIED BY CODEPAGE=932 INSERT INTO prd_category_master_l10N (GUID,CATEGORYGUID,LOCALEGUID,REALMGUID,CATEGORY_NAME)
SQL3109N  The utility is beginning to load data from file
"/home/user/beetri/cat.csv".

SQL3124W  The field value in row "1" and column "1" cannot be converted to a
PACKED DECIMAL value, but the target column is not nullable.  The row was not
loaded.